# AWS CodeBuild DOWNLOAD_SOURCE Runtime error (*exec.ExitError: exit status 1)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have automated build with AWS CodePipeline, it worked fine, but suddenly today it started to fail with this weird error message, which I can't fine anywhere to understand what's going on.

```
Container] 2017/12/26 16:42:52 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2017/12/26 16:42:52 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2017/12/26 16:42:53 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2017/12/26 16:42:53 Runtime error (*exec.ExitError: exit status 1)
```

This is during `DOWNLOAD_SOURCE` Phase, which is blocked me to understand the issue, because this seems to be on AWS's side, not from my deployment configuration.

[image]

Is there anybody who is faced same issue, or know how to figure out the problem itself?

Thanks!

Comment: It is very hard to debug without more details. I request please create a new thread under AWS CodeBuild forums https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=230

Comment: ok thanks, will try that

Answer (score 0):

I've gone mad with this exact same issue. If you google DOWNLOAD_SOURCE `"Runtime error (*exec.ExitError: exit status 1)"` it is the ONLY result.

In my case the issue was wrong zip file format.

The correct way of zip-ing up the source is:

```
cd somedir ; zip -r ../zipped.zip . * ; cd ..
```

I was using:

```
zip -r bless_builder.zip somedir/*
```

In [aws codebuild user guide](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-codebuild-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/getting-started.md#getting-started-upload-source-code) they do mention it:

> Important
>
> Do not include the (root directory name) directory, only the
>   directories and files contained in the (root directory name)
>   directory.

But I swear they could be at least more creative with the error code!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, format your code, that make the answer clearer.